# If List Items cross more than 5 remove items and show next 5 list items javascript html

Tags: javascript, html

I m trying to dynamically generate a UL list, but the issue is list is generating list of 1000 items. so I want to limit the list,

Below is list which will keep on generating dynamically

```html
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
ff
gg
hh
ii
jj
kk
ll
mm
nn
.
.
.
nth
```

I want to divide the UL list in group so it should show 1st 5 list items and then remove it and show next 5 list items and again steps should repeat.

I m generating list in `<uL><li>`

I tried this

```js
$(function () {
    $('span').click(function () {
        $('#datalist li:hidden').slice(0, 2).show();
        if ($('#datalist li').length == $('#datalist li:visible').length) {
            $('span ').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
ul li:nth-child(n+3) {
    display:none;
}
ul li {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
span {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="datalist">
  <li>aa</li>
  <li>bb</li>
  <li>cc</li>
  <li>dd</li>
  <li>ee</li>
  <li>ff</li>
  <li>gg</li>
  <li>hh</li>
  <li>ii</li>
  <li>jj</li>
</ul>
<span>readmore</span>
```

Comment: You should provide the existing code you already have so it's easier to help you

Comment: @Brad plz check

Comment: @NicolasGarnier plz check i had updated my question

Comment: @SumanAcoustics thanks for adding your efforts.

Comment: @SumanAcoustics: Go through this: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/7ntt2964/

Comment: what dictates the grouping? so for example lets say you want only 5 items begining with the letter A then the next 5 begining with the letter B.

Comment: I want to remove the 1st 5 items and display the 2nd 5 items, and repeat the process again. My UL list is generating dynamically one after another so whenever the list items cross 5, it should be removed

Comment: @Abhitalks not working as my list is generating dynamically list items one after another in foreach loop

Comment: Ok so each time the person click "read more" it shows them the next 5 on the list?

Comment: I dont want any butto to be clicked it should automatically remove old items and show new items

Comment: What dictates when it should show the next 5 items? you want it on a timer?

Comment: Suppose the list has 5 items. So it should show that, but if UL list crosses more than 5 items so it should remove the 1st 5 items and show the next 5 items

Comment: Mate you really need to be clearer. So if you have a list of 15 items. You want to hide the items 1-5 and show 6-10, what about 11-15?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, you want to cycle through the list 5 at a time? or you just want to only show 5? what do you want to do with the rest? If you are cycling through them, when do you do each cycle? on a timer, orr when someone clicks a button? what?

Comment: You're telling me you dont want them to click a button but your code is running on the click of the readmore span $('span').click(function () {

Comment: UL list is generating dynamically. Suppose the list has generated 5 items, so it show the 5 items, if list has been added with new items so it should remove the 1st 5 items and show next 5 items. Again it should check if new item has been added so it should show next items and remove previous items'

Comment: So you only ever want to show the last 5?

Comment: yes the last. My list is generating through foreach so it will dynamically geenrate the list items so i want to remove old one and show new one so at the end it should show last 5 items

Comment: removing and showing of items should be dynamically as per foreach loop

Comment: Have added a solution that will only display the last 5 items

Answer (score 0):

So if the goal is to only show the last 5 items, you can do this with just CSS using `nth-last-of-type`.

Note: ignore the javascript and the button, its just there to demonstrate the adding of an item to the list.

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
 var lastItem = $('#datalist li:last-child').html();
  var nextItem = parseInt(lastItem)+1;
  $('#datalist').append('<li>'+nextItem+'</li>') 
});
```

```css
ul#datalist > li {
  display: none;
}
ul#datalist > li:nth-last-of-type(-n+5) {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="datalist">
  <li>01</li>
  <li>02</li>
  <li>03</li>
  <li>04</li>
  <li>05</li>
  <li>06</li>
  <li>07</li>
  <li>08</li>
  <li>09</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
<button>Add item</button>
```

Comment: then you must be doing something else to effect the outcome as this method does work, its working in the snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a JS solution that will remove all but the last 5 items.

Again, please ignore the button thats adding the items, this is only here to demonstrate what happens when an item is added.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var lastItem = $('#datalist li:last-child').html();
  var nextItem = parseInt(lastItem) + 1;
  $('#datalist').append('<li>' + nextItem + '</li>')
  filterList();
});

function filterList() {
  $("#datalist > li").not(":nth-last-of-type(-n+5)").remove();
}

filterList();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="datalist">
  <li>01</li>
  <li>02</li>
  <li>03</li>
  <li>04</li>
  <li>05</li>
  <li>06</li>
  <li>07</li>
  <li>08</li>
  <li>09</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
<button>Add item</button>
```